# Qt internationalization system with different positioned strings

Tags: qt, internationalization, translation

I'm aware that there are some languages that writes the order of some characters differently than the common latin languages. E.g.: a percentage number in English would be like "100%", while in Persian it would be "/100" (the symbol comes before the number).

Question: how to consider that in the Qt internationalization system in an intelligent way?

I first thought about this code:

```
myLabel->setText(tr("%1%2").arg(value).arg(tr("%")));
```

So what would happen is that, in the Qt Linguist, the translator would change the order of the replacement fields:

```
%1%2 -> in Persian translation -> %2%1
```

I checked that in my code and I found out that while in the normal (English) translation everything was fine, when I changed to the file containing the performed translation, a bug would occur: the number to be shown was never complete having one less number that what I had written. So e.g. if I chose "99%", it would show "%9", and if I set only "9%", I would have just "%".

The problem disappeared when I put a space between %1 and %2 both in the source code as well as in the translation (%2 %1). Since ISO xxxxx says that the % should be placed with a space between it and the correspondent number, no problem for this specific situation. But what If I wanted to have both symbols without a space between each other? How should it be done?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the problem you described exists. However I would solve this problem in the following way:

```
QString sPer = QString("%%1").arg(value); // %99
QString sEng = QString("%1%").arg(value); // 99%
```

So that

```
%1% -> in Persian translation -> %%1
```

Comment: I liked your idea :) No reason to put % inside a specific call to QObject::tr() after all! (Although I'll still put a space to follow the ISO XXXX standard)

Answer (score 0):

Put the percentage inside the string to translate, something like

myLabel->setText(tr("%%1").arg(value))

even better, I think I would add a disambiguation string (Qt "old style" comment)

```
myLabel->setText(tr("%%1", "Show the number with a percentage").arg(value))
```

or maybe a new style translation comment like this

```
//: Show the number with a percentage
myLabel->setText(tr("%%1").arg(value))
```

Translator comments have issues of their own, you might be better off using a Qt disambiguation string like the preceding example.

Putting a disambiguation string (or a translator comment) will let your translator know what they are translating...

Let the translators decide where they want to put the percentage, don't try to handle it in the code as somebody else suggested, it is not scalable, you can't start handling this in the code like that, what if you need to use another character or formatting for another language?

It might even be possible that Qt might have calls to handle number formatting but I can't seem to find them at the moment and I am not fully sure how we handle them in the Qt application I work on...

If putting a % alone doesn't work, try to precede it with \, it might be necessary to escape it, I am not sure...